# how to put php and node.js togther

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io

I have test node.js + socket.io with port 8080 yesterday

i found that the frontend page which receive the data and send request must defined as HTML

which mean, i can use a mvc php combine with node.js and socket.io

is there any way to do that?

more if i define the node server as localhost:8080
i cant call the web server by other place, such as localhost

unlike nature websocket, i can use the socket anywhere, and i just need to define the socket address as localhost:8080

anyway to solve out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run node on port 8080 run php on port 8081. Use php to run your frontend HTML and JavaScript include the frontend socket.io library and connect to localhost:8080 (the node server)

```
// client side code
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
```

This is untested, and I don't know if this is what you want, or if it will work.

Comment: socket.io can not inclued in php - localhost:8081, it only allow to  localhost:8080, otherwise, file not found

Comment: Like that <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>, it is defined in index.html, which using express framework to call the this html

Comment: @user192344 go find a copy of it and put it somewhere on your server or if both servers are running use `<script src="http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`.

Comment: SUCCESS by using server:port/socket.io/socket.io.js, THXXXX